# How can I call another function to get string data

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<malloc.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

typedef struct pre_load{
    char *pre_ip;
    int data2;
    char data3;
}pre_load;
int a(pre_load pre){
    char *test;
    test = (char*)calloc(1, 256);
    strcpy(test, "test127.0.0.0.1");
    pre.pre_ip = (char*)calloc(1, 256);
    strcpy(pre.pre_ip, test);
    return 0;
};
int main(){
    pre_load pre;
    pre.pre_ip = (char*)calloc(1, 256);
    a(pre);

    printf("%s", pre.pre_ip);
    system("pause");
}
```

I add this function to test a procject

Why I got nothing without any error??
It confuses me for a long time.
I think I should study about pointer again.

Comment: `a()` has a memory leak - you leak the memory pointed to by `test`.

Comment: Don't change your question into a totally new one, you could ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a(pre_load pre)
```

You are passing `pre` by value, so anything you modified in the function `a` doesn't affect `pre` in `main`. Instead, declare the function passing a pointer:

```
void a(pre_load *pre){
    char *test = calloc(1, 256);
    strcpy(test, "test127.0.0.0.1");
    pre->pre_ip = calloc(1, 256);
    strcpy(pre->pre_ip, test);
    free(test);
};
```

And pass it in `main`:

```
pre_load pre;
a(&pre);
```

Note that you have memory leaks in your original code.